# What is SockJSAdapter and why it is running endlessly

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a `Shiny-app` hosted in Ubuntu, attached is the current snapshot of processes running
[image]
As you see a significant chunk of memory is being consumed by something called `SockJSAdapter` which is related to Shiny-server. I have noticed that this process starts when I run my App in Browser and it keeps running even after I close that App in Browser.

Can someone shed more light what this process is, and why it keeps running even after I close the App? Do I need to do something in my `Shiny-app (ui.R or server.R)` so that this process will be killed just the moment user closes the App?

*Shiny-server version I am using:*

```
apt-cache showpkg shiny-server
Package: shiny-server
Versions:
1.5.6.875 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/dpkg/status
                  MD5: 5692122708280493808d4d49f42a0475


Reverse Depends:
Dependencies:
1.5.6.875 - libc6 (2 2.7) r-base (2 2.15.1)
Provides:
1.5.6.875 -
Reverse Provides:
```

Thanks for any pointer.

Comment: im trying to understand this as well. Please post if you figured out.

Comment: I'm also looking for more information about this. If anyone has any insight please post.

Answer (score 2):

I can find some information about this problem in this [shiny-server issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/155). I can't parse the comments related to proxy usage and shiny-server. I also don't understand anything about web sockets, which I guess [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs) is designed to handle. I can safely kill all dangling sockjsadapter.R processes with `pkill -f SockJSAdapter.R` and restart the shiny-server.

I would love to know a way to ensure that these zombie processes do not reoccur every time a user closes a shiny app.