# Multiple R Shiny processes

Tags: r, bash, shell, shiny, shiny-server

I have this several Shiny sleeping processes consuming some resources. Do you know how they are created and why they remain?

[htop command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jajyM.png)

I think it slows down the response time.

I found these topics but I couldn'l really get a final solution.
References:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701661/what-is-sockjsadapter-and-why-it-is-running-endlessly?rq=1)
[link2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/g5FbYp5Iyj8)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this question.

The sleeping processes are/were caused by reactiveTimer function. So in order to solve it you just need to add a second argument like this:

reactiveTimer(300000, session = getDefaultReactiveDomain())

When you close your app session it will also stop/kill the sleeping processes.